# Get extension of videos uploaded to flickr

Tags: video, flickr

How can I get the original file extension of videos uploaded to flickr?

I'm constructing the url to download the original video using
`http://www.flickr.com/photos/{user-id|custom-url}/{photo-id}/play/{site|mobile|hd|orig}/{secret|originalsecret}/` Previously, the http response headers would contain a content-disposition field that contained the filename and extension. Sometime in the last few months, however, the content-disposition stopped showing up in the response headers.

flickr.photo.getInfo doesn't return any extension specific information and the extras parameter `original_format` returns the preview image format, not the actual video extension.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I too would like to know how to get the file extension for a video for my [flickr-dumpr](https://github.com/fredrikaverpil/flickr-dumpr). I can't see how this can be done right now.

Comment: Please Yahoo, do something about this and fix your API!